# DataTables warning on Find and Merge page - Upgraded to 5.0 from 4.7.17

Tags: wordpress, duplicate-contacts

I'm Running Civi 5.0.0 with Wordpress 4.9.5

I'm looking to troubleshoot the following warning. It comes up on the *Find and Merge* page after select any of my Find and Merge rules - no results are shown despite duplicate contacts existing,

> DataTables warning: table id=dupePairs - Invalid JSON response. For
>   more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/1

ajax "response" in Chrome's tab shows what looks like the page's html file - I have no idea where to search for the actual ajax:
[image: Response tab in Chrome]

No error is recorded in Civi's log.

It looks and sounds a lot like [this bug](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20556). Which is odd because I assume it would have fixed when upgrading to Civi 5.0

This staging site was running 4.7.17 until I updated to 5.0 (I had to manually create the columns card_type, and pan_truncation in the civicrm_financial_trxn table to complete the update).

Looking at [the github patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10503/files), my dedupefind.tpl *appears* to contain the patched lines. Is there a part of the patch I'm missing via the WP copy or something else?

Comment: That looks like a different error/bug than the one on issues.civicrm.org. Is there anything in the apache/httpd log like an error 500 or 403/404 for the ajax call? Or can you manually see which ajax call/url is returning the invalid json and what the response looks like?

Comment: If the following isn't enough I'll have to look up how to check the ajax/url stuff. As far as I know, I only have access to the CPanel Error Log, which doesn't show anything recorded. Looking at my browser's inspector everything is loaded except for the civicrm logo "logo16px" (no idea why it's been missing since the install) and a 302 redirect from .../wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contact/dedupefind&reset=1&rgid=10&gid=&limit=&action=renew to .../wp-admin/.../dedupefind&reset=1&rgid=10&gid=&limit=&action=update

Comment: Sorry, the ajax stuff isn't in my realm of knowledge and I forgot about what I read yesterday. The ajax "response" in Chrome's tab shows what looks like the page's html file - I have no idea where to search for the actual ajax: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4jnz9czoa2i4htz/Ajax%20response.png?dl=0

Comment: The browser inspector should work. That screenshot seems like the wrong screenshot though.

Comment: You would be correct - I thought it was a weird review to leave for Whitman's Leaves of Grass.

This was the intended screenshot (I doubled checked it): https://www.dropbox.com/s/zqpb35yaoraz5x5/Ajax%20response.png?dl=0

Comment: Probably a bot review hehe. If you scroll down I expect there is some error text somewhere in there. If you visit that url manually what do you see?

Comment: I'm not sure what to look for but the file itself is html and calls for scripts.  Opening the URL only loads CiviCRM home. Edit: Here's the file, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/kyt1m18z3eomrkf/file-with-ajax-issue.txt

Comment: Try visiting /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1 to rebuild the routing table. It seems like it's not recognizing how to route civicrm/ajax/dedupefind.

Comment: I have the same problem on the Joomla version of 5.0.0. No error in the CiviCRM log or the Apache log. Tried rebuild&reset, but no change.

Comment: @Demerit Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't seem to have any effect.

And Jern; So it's not just me? Hm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken a look at this & a patch should be out next week (I'm expecting that to mean we will release 5.0.1 - the flexibility to do that being the main motivation for the renumbering)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Edit: Is there a place where I can try the patch out before? I need dedupe to test some issues I'm having with my database.

Comment: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11975

Comment: Thank you for posting this - I just spent the last hour trying to figure this out - glad there is a solution

Comment: patched it with old code - did the trick

Comment: @user4278 Friggin' beautiful. Works again. Many thanks.