# Datatables Warning in Find and Merge Page

Tags: duplicate-contacts, error-page, datatables

This issue is similar to [this one](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24496/datatables-warning-on-find-and-merge-page-upgraded-to-5-0-from-4-7-17). The only difference is that we are on CiviCRM 5.22.1.

## Problem

The following error pops-up when use the 'Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts' page (civicrm/contact/dedupefind) then I try to search for contacts or when I modify the filters and the search input has a value:
[image: Datatables error because ajax request returns 500]
[image: The ajax request]

## Steps to Replicate (must have contacts with same first name and last name which https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ has)

1. Go to the Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts page (route is civicrm/contact/deduperules?reset=1 or access it via Contacts > Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts).
2. Create a new rule for detecting duplicates using their first name and last name only. I added First Name and Last Name as the fields and they have the same weight and the sum of their weights is the Weight Threshold to Consider Contacts 'Matching'. For example, weight treshold for First Name and Last Name is both 1 and the Weight Threshold to Consider Contacts 'Matching' is 2.
   [image: Name only rule for finding duplicates]
3. Use the just recently created rule to look for duplicates. For the group, select 'All Contacts'.
   [image: Select 'All Contacts' as the group]
4. Attempt a search using the search bar on the top right of the list of duplicates; you should get the following error.
   [image]

Is anyone else having this issue and how might we fix this?

Comment: it may be worth confirming if you can replicate this on one of the civicrm.org demo sites at the bottom of this page https://civicrm.org/demo

Comment: Hi Pete, yeah, I tried the English demo and I do get the same exact error.

Comment: can you add a link to the exact form you use that throws the error on eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/deduperules?reset=1 and any prior steps i need to take to replicate

Comment: @petednz-fuzion thanks for looking into this. I've just added the steps to replicate this problem.

Comment: your rule was still there when i tested it. i went to https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/dedupefind?reset=1&action=update&rgid=8 but did not see the error

Comment: i added "ca.civicrm.logviewer" in case it can be replicated and some more info can be gleaned

Comment: what  browser are you using (in case it might relate)

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Chrome on Mac (Version 92.0.4515.131)

Comment: v odd. same as me but i didn't see the Warning

Comment: @petednz-fuzion did you put anything in the search bar? I get it as soon as I type into the search bar.

Comment: I concur that problem exists. are you up for adding a GitLab ticket? https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/

Comment: i have mentioned it here https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/d3z4fuq8rbyitbbsgia853eq6h

Comment: @petednz-fuzion thanks so much! I'll submit an issue.